# Why do I keep getting .addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, event-listener

So I'm working with a JW Player and everything is working great except for one piece of functionality I'm working on. When I run the code I get a console error:
**Uncaught TypeError: upTop.addEventListener is not a functio**n

Here is the code:

```
                var upTop = document.getElementsByClassName('playlist-item');

                upTop.addEventListener('click', function() {
                jwplayer.setup({autostart: true, floating: {dismissable: true}});
                       window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                });
```

Is there some kind of syntax error I'm missing here?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list

Answer (score 5):

Calling getElementsByClassName works differently from getElementById. Multiple elements can have the same class name so what is returned is an array. For example, if you want the first item returned because you know there is only one element with the class then

```
var upTop = document.getElementsByClassName('playlist-item')[0];
```

would suffice. Otherwise, you can loop through all items in upTop and add the event listener to all of them. In pure JS:

```
for (var i=0; i < upTop.length;i++) {
 upTop[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    wplayer.setup({autostart: true, floating: {dismissable: true}});
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

UpTop is a list of elements rather than the element it self.

If you are trying to apply it to one element you can use
 `upTop[0].addEventListener`

Or if its multiple loop over them and bind them individually

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` and `HTMLCollection` doesnot have property `addEventListener`

#### For Only First Element

```
var upTop = document.querySelector('.playlist-item');
```

#### Using `for` loop

If you want to add event listener on all the elements then use `for` loop.

```
var upTop = document.getElementsByClassName('playlist-item');
for(let i = 0;i<upTop.length;i++){
    upTop[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
       ...
    });
}
```

#### Using `forEach`

Or you can convert it into array and use `forEach()`

```
var upTop = [...document.getElementsByClassName('playlist-item')];
upTop.forEach(a => a.addEventListener(click,() => ...))
```

#### Using jQuery

```
$('.playlist-item').click(function(){
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off refactoring your code to take advantage of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Essentially the technique is used to delegate event handling to a single parent container - this way we don't have to add an event listener on each and every element that we want to register a click handler on.

Here's an example:

```js
//A parent container for event delegation purposes
var containerEl = document.querySelector('#playlist-items-container');

//Add the event handler to the parent container and analyze the target when an element is clicked on
containerEl.addEventListener('click', e => {
  //Check if a //playlist-item was clicked
  if (e.target.className.indexOf('playlist-item') > -1) {
    console.log(`${e.target.textContent} was clicked`);
    //Do jwplayer.setup(...);
    //Do window.scrollTo(...);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="playlist-items-container">
  <div class="playlist-item">Playlist item 1</div>
  <div class="playlist-item">Playlist item 2</div>
  <div class="playlist-item">Playlist item 3</div>
  <div class="playlist-item">Playlist item 4</div>
</div>
```